# Why is the UUID split into chunks like XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX?

Tags: uuid

Most developers have seen UUIDs (Universally unique identifier), but what is the reason the UUID is split into chunks like XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX?

The UUID is just a 128-bit number, and could be stored/displayed/saved in any way possible, but why is commonly represented by 8, 4, 4, 4, 12 hexadecimal characters separated by dashes?

Is there some logical reason why this is the case?

Comment: This may help: https://segment.com/blog/a-brief-history-of-the-uuid/

Comment: How would knowing the answer alter the way you program? If it wouldn't then this question is inappropriate for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

This format improves readability by breaking down the UUID(s) into smaller, more digestible chunks. By separating the characters with dashes, it becomes easier to read though.

Also, the 1-2-3-4-5 structure aligns with the most common type of UUIDs, known as version 4 UUIDs.

Comment: That does not really answer the question.  Readability is one aspect but on its own does not explain the number of digits in each group.